# PHP Bitmask says true when it should be false

Tags: php, bit

I am comparing two variables with a bitwise AND, and it shouldn't return true but it does. Here is my code,

```
if($d & $w){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

where `$d` is 15 and `$w` is 31.

Why does it return true when the bitmasks are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not **comparing** the two variables, you are **and**ing them instead. Whith a bitwise AND you cannot compare anything.

**($d & $w)** means $d AND $w, where AND is the boolean AND operator. You are anding two integer variables here which will give an integer too. And an integer is interpreted as TRUE in a comparison if it is not null.

$d is binary 01111
$w is binary 11111
($d & $w) obviously is binary 01111. If you do a *var_dump($d & $w)* you see that the result is an integer, not a boolean;

So, if you mean to compare the ANDed value, you should choose a comparison construct, like this:

```
if ( ($d & $w) == $d ) ...
```

which means: if the ANDed value of $d and $w equals $d.

### Code example

```
<?php

$d = 15;
$w = 31;
$res = ($d & $w);
echo '$d=' . decbin($d) . '<br />';
echo '$w=' . decbin($w) . '<br />';
echo '($d & $w)=' . decbin($res) . '<br />';

// Boolean AND only
if($d & $w){
    echo '($d & $w) is true' . '<br />';
} else {
    echo '($d & $w) is false' . '<br />';
}

// Comparison with boolean AND
if ( ($d & $w) == $d ) {
    echo '(($d & $w) == $d) is true' . '<br />';
} else {
    echo '(($d & $w) == $d) is false' . '<br />';
}

// Simple comparison
if ($d == $w) {
    echo '($d == $w) is true' . '<br />';
} else {
    echo '($d == $w) is false' . '<br />';
}
```

### Result

```
$d=1111
$w=11111
($d & $w)=1111
($d & $w) is true
(($d & $w) == $d) is true
($d == $w) is false
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that this is how it worked, according to the article I read, it should have worked the first way, however I guess that article is wrong. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Because 15 and 31 are greater than 0 which is false, so the bits in the set rate as true.  What I think you are wanting is:

```
if(($d & $w)== true){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

You need to use parentheses to ensure the desired precedence.

Comment: ($d & $w) will give binary 01111 (decimal 15), which is interpreted as TRUE since it is greater than ZERO. But it will never be a result of type boolean. So strictly taken the result will never be TRUE. If you would code if (($d & $w)===true) the result would be FALSE.

Comment: I referenced http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php as my basis, I understand that it would return false, but I did not think it would be typing or evaluating to boolean.